# keypad debouncer configuration RC Value

Tags: button, debounce, keypad

I have keypad with for buttons and common signal connected to ground..

I noticed two configuration for debouncing as shown bellow..

[image]

**Question:**
- Will the both configuration work correctly? 
when button (pressed > Low) (released > High) 
- How to select the pull-up resistor ( R1 - R4) and debouncing circuit (R5 - R8 / C1 - C4)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either one will work - the cap doesn’t care as long as it has a charge/discharge path. I have a preference for #2 since the cap discharge path to the switch is via GND.

The RC time constant you select depends on how much contact bounce you have. Figure on the order of ms to tens of ms, but check with a scope if you can.

If possible consider adding a Schmitt-trigger buffer if your receiving device isn’t of that type.

Here’s a reference by Jack Ganssle, a well-known contributor to EDN and other electronic pubs. https://my.eng.utah.edu/~cs5780/debouncing.pdf

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the controller thresholds and current ratings and specified bounce time and amount of wear and tear.   carbon, metal and other contact materials all have different responses with spring or dimple response times.  a good switch with 1-2 ms bounce time is expected. But your control scan frame time is also a limiting factor as well as the user fastest cycle rate that you may  want to restrict or not.

Rise time of the R1C =T1 value limits current V/R . If metal non- Au 
Plated  buttons are used, you may want a 50mA impulse wetting current and rise time does not matter.

decay time depends on the controller input bias current and R2 pull-up x C =T2

- If the T1 and T2 is too long then rapid button presses may drift into the middle indeterminate state.
- I would suggest T2 >= 2x specified bounce time and > key  scan cycle time to avoid being undetected, then T1 can be as short as you want but limit current severely for carbon buttons but increase current greatly for non gold plated contacts.  Gold plated contacts don’t need a wetting current unless your environment is corrosive (salty humidity) or these are really cheap 1u” flash gold plated contacts.

Thus the R2/R1 ratios can be very high or low depending on the button contacts. C only needs to exceed the circuit stray capacitance by some wide margin.  100pF~ 1nF ??

Comment: In case you do not understand my answer this is more detailed for some to comprehend , so ask what you do not know. Don’t be a troll and down vote

Comment: Do you want me to do the work for you, or can you specify your own scan rates and link the button specs and compute RC values as I indicated, ?  Ignore the idiots who downvote with out the intelligence to ask a question or comment.

Comment: Two -2 vote of uninformed anal isis ignorance.